# Does killing yourself count as an elimination?

Tags: overwatch

I was playing the other day, and I managed to kill myself with RipTire while clearing the point. I know you don't get an elimination if it says you died, but it actually said that I eliminated myself and gave me fire points. Did killing myself like this actually give me an elimination?

[Video of it happening](https://youtu.be/f7xl73CnFdY)

Comment: RIP-Tire might actually be a special case. It might consider itself to be its own entity. If this is the case, it's probably a bug.

Comment: It wouldn't happen though for something like D.Va, since you never transfer control to MEKA, you just send it off to blow up. RIP-tire hijacks control.

Comment: If this is indeed the case, I think the case is a bug. It is contradictory to get fire points due to friendly fire. You should consider opening a ticket with the video linked here.

Comment: I got PotG once by blowing myself up along with two enemies. Even though it was pretty hilarious and they were point eliminations, I'm beginning to wonder if the PotG algorithm included my death in its calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Normally, self-damage from explosives and the like does not give the kill to anyone.

RIP-Tire's case is different. It's the same kind of entity as an hero, so kills CAN be attributed to it. This means if you kill Junkrat with the tire, it will count as a kill and it'll even show "Eliminated by [yourname]" along with "[yourname] eliminated".

Fun fact : for some reason, this counts as a shutdown, so there have been some cases of Junkrat players getting PotG by killing only themselves.

Comment: Killing yourself with RIP-Tire doesn't always count as an elimination, though. Do you know in which cases it does? Also just to be clear, you mean that killing yourself in such manner does give you an elimination, right?